Cannot get decriptions for events from ETW Providers
I created a trace on my Windows 10 laptop using this logman command:
logman create trace "Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-File" -p Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-File 0x1800 -o "C:\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-File.etl"

then I started the trace.
Overall, the trace works normally. It created an .etl file in the path I specified and logged the events it could with the keywords I enabled.
However, there is a problem when viewing the log. If I open the .etl file with Event Viewer, it prompts me to save a copy in .evtx format. I did. But when I view the events, it said:

The description for Event ID 27 from source Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-File cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

Other information of the event is visible normally, like filepath,... Just the description for the event could not be generated.
Has anyone faced this issue or know how to solve this?

By far not all events can be viewed with Event Viewer. Most traced data can only be viewed with WPA (Windows Performance Analyzer) or PerfView or other third party tools. You would not get what you want anyway because e.g. ReadArgs_V1 does not include the file name of a read event so you would be lost in the viewer.

Event 27 comes in two flavors: RenamePath and RenamePath_V1 which is probably too much for Event viewer which is rather simplistic.
